# Connection issue with sql-Raspberry PI

Tags: sql, node.js

I am currently using Raspberry Pi as my Server for IOT. I am trying to connect my client side to server, so that it can communicate with the server. But I am getting following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\plugload-workaround\plugLoad\plugload-pi\plugload\production\plugLoad4.php on line 178

Could you please help me in resolving that.
If the issue is due to security reasons, please help me in correcting the security details.

Comment: May be [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/52794/how-do-i-allow-remote-access-to-mysql-using-xampp) could the related question.

Comment: What are your connection details? Is your MySQL server running? It is accepting connections from the network (rather than just via sockets and/or localhost)? What’s the output of `netstat -an | grep 3306` on the server?

Comment: MYSQL is running in my server. It is fetching data properly. The server is raspberry pi

Comment: Hi everyone, Its working now. The reason being, the static IP was not set for the pi. Hence the IP is getting changed often. Once I set my static IP, I can able to connect to the server from client .